# PHP User Set Display Order

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, dynamic-data

I am trying to build a CMS and was wondering how I can have it so the user on the backend can dynamically set the pages display order. I know with MySQL how to the ORDER BY but I want the user to able to say this page should be first, etc. I am not even sure how to approach this so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Add a priority field to your pages (or the list of pages that you are displaying) then make that editable somehow.

Comment: You would usually maintain some sort of sorting index in a separate `int` column

Comment: Are you wanting any logged in user to be able to set this, or an admin-type user?

Comment: @Surreal the only 'users' on this CMS are admins. So I guess any user can update it, because users are admins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an 'order' INT field to your 'pages' table, or where ever you are storing the data for those. Then just give the user the option of editing that somehow, such as drag n' dropping the page, then, when setting up the navigation, just order by the order field.

Comment: Ok. I got an orderby field now, do you know of any javascript drag and drop libraries that can do this? I am searching now but only found one. Any help would be great!

Comment: @Nathan Stanford II: You could use jQuery Sortables -- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Sortable. Here's an example using PHP and MySQL to get you started as well: http://coder1.com/articles/jquery-sortables-php-and-mysql

Comment: @stealthyninja just what I needed to get started! Thanks so much! I will get right on this and hopefully get it figured out soon.